# How to mock a dataclass

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

How can I create a mock of a `dataclass` so that `asdict` works on it?

This doesn't seem to work:

```
>>> from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict
>>> @dataclass
... class A:
...     foo: int
>>> asdict(A(foo=1))
{'foo': 1}
>>> from unittest import mock
>>>
>>> asdict(mock.create_autospec(A))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/dataclasses.py", line 1072, in asdict
    raise TypeError("asdict() should be called on dataclass instances")
TypeError: asdict() should be called on dataclass instances
```

*Note: Python 3.8.5*

Comment: That example worked well in my Python version 3.7.3 in Windows, but using Python 3.7.6 in Ubuntu didn't work. Can you try Python3.7.3?

Comment: It really doesn't work for me in Python 3.8.5 @robbinc91